# Difference between (BOOL) and boolValue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

What is the difference between these two lines?

```
alertObj.AlertAddressed=[[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)] boolValue];

alertObj.AlertAddressed=(BOOL)[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)];
```

I'm getting a different result for these two lines - why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is very good reference. [BOOL / bool / Boolean / NSCFBoolean](http://nshipster.com/bool/)

Comment: I don't think there is any need for NSNumber here at all. `alertObj.AlertAddressed = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9) != 0` should do.

Answer (score 2):

First one gives you actual bool value.

Second one type cast to `BOOL` the result of

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how good you are at pointers but I try to explain

First of all when you get an NSNumber it is an object, and the value of an object is at first it's pointer (so something like 0x0000af) this is simple an adress in the memory, and this address contains your NSNUmber wich contains the actual value (so let's say a bool information in your example)

It's pretty simple, when you do

```
(BOOL)alertObj.AlertAddressed=(BOOL)[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)];
```

what actually happen is the try to cast the 0x0000af part to a bool value... NOT what NSNumber contains (what you actually get depends on the current Pointer of the object when you try this)

```
alertObj.AlertAddressed=[[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)] boolValue];
```

this is something actually implemented in NSNumber and therefore it completly respects what the object does and gives you the bool saved in your NSNumber, and not a cast from it's pointer

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber` is an object, `BOOL` is a primitive type.
`NSNumber` is a class that wraps numbers, but you can't use to make operations, if you want you should unwrap calling a specific method. 
 Since `NSNumber` is an object your variable is a pointer holding a reference to an object, not a value. 
The first line is correct, the second is wrong because you are casting a pointer to a bool type.

Answer (score 0):

`alertObj.AlertAddressed=[[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)] boolValue];` *This will convert you value to BOOL*

`alertObj.AlertAddressed=(BOOL)[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)]`;*This is like casting.* Considers `[NSNumber numberWithBool:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 9)]` will return bool value.